# Compilation error in CookieCollection iteration inside Async block

Tags: visual-studio, f#

I have noticed a strange behaviour during the iteration over a CookieCollection done inside an Async block. Basically the compiler is not able to infer the type of the collection.

Follows an image of the error:

[image]

Is this an issue in the F# compiler/editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the loop work in the async block, you need to cast the collection first:

```
async {
    for c in httpWebResponse.Cookies |> Seq.cast<Cookie> do ()
}
```

This converts the collection from `IEnumerable` to `IEnumerable<'T>`. As you have seen, this wasn't necessary when using this line outside of async workflow:

```
for c in httpWebResponse.Cookies do ()
```

The reason for this is that these two constructs are not the same, despite having the same syntax.

The one above is the 'generic' in-built `for` loop that can handle different types of collections (using the IEnumerable interface with some caveats, as outlined in [F# 3.0 spec](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/), §6.5.6 Sequence Iteration Expressions). The other one in the async block is the async builder's `For` method, and that method is explicitly defined to expect a `seq<'a>` (in other words,`IEnumerable<'T>`).

So no, it's not a bug. It's the internals of async showing through.

Comment: For an explanation of the behaviour of the built-in `for` loop see _§6.5.6  Sequence Iteration Expressions_ of the [F# 3.0 spec](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/). Basically, if the `Current` property has return type `obj` and the collection type has an `Item` property with a more specific (non-object) return type, than this is used instead.

Answer (score 1):

No, as the error suggests, [`CookieCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.CookieCollection.aspx) does not implement `IEnumerable<'a>` but only the non-generic `IEnumerable`. You need to use `Seq.cast<'a>`:

```
for cookie in httpWebResponse.Cookies |> Seq.cast<Cookie> do
   ...
```